# gpilot-install-file in a cron job?

Tags: gnome, cron

I have a cron job that generates some .pdb files, and I'd like to automatically queue them for installation at the next sync. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get gpilot-install-file to work in a cron job. It requires a display (why??), so I gave it a "--display=:0.0" option. Then it complained it couldn't get the PDA list, so I gave it a "--pilot=MyPDA" option.

```
/usr/bin/gpilot-install-file --later --display=:0.0 --pilot=MyPDA myfile.pdb
```

Now I get this:

> (gpilot-install-file:4959):
>   gpilotd-CRITICAL **:
>   gnome_pilot_client_install_file:
>   assertion `self->gpilotddaemon!=NULL'
>   failed

Is there a way to get this to work, or is there some other way to get files into the install queue for gnome-pilot from a cron job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the "gpilotd" daemon running? It seems that some environment variables may still be missing that `gpilot-install-file` needs to do its work. Compare the output of the `env` command in your Desktop terminal against `env` run from cron. (You've already identified one required difference: the "DISPLAY" variable.)

Sometimes things like the D-Bus service environment ("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS") are needed, etc. Try defining things until you've got it working. To extract these variables from your running Desktop session, you can read them out of `/proc`:

```
xargs -0 -n1 < /proc/$(pidof gnome-session)/environ | grep what-you-need
```

Comment: Yes, gpilotd is definitely running. I can sync, but I don't get my files installed. I'll look at the environment variables and see if I can discover anything.

Comment: Hallelujah! It works! Setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS did the trick. Thank you! Here's a well-earned 75 rep (accept + upvote + bounty).